# How to make time format in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have to display this expiryDate on two different screens , this value is coming from api .  Number 1 expiryDate is working coming in formate , but no 2 is not working , getting error invalid time 
 I am getting error invalid time , please suggest .

// 1.Below  code is displaying proper format

```
expiryDate:
date: "2019-04-02T15:17:16.016Z"
__typename: "Date"
```

// 2 . In below format i am getting error invalid time .

```
expiryDate:
date: "2099-12-30T23:00:00.000Z"
__typename: "Date"
```

// Below code is using to format my expiryDate  and after that i am displaying expDate

```
let expDate = new Date(expiryDate).toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-').reverse().join('-') 
              + ' ' 
              + new Date(expiryTime).toISOString().split('T')[1].split('.')[0];
```

I have to display in this formate " 2019-04-02 15:17:16 "

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question. As it currently stands it's hard to understand what does and doesn't work in your code.

Comment: thanks for ur time .. I have updated question

Comment: What is `expiryTime`? Why are you reversing the date components? Please add an **executable** example.

Answer (score 3):

The beauty of the React Native is that it supports lots of JS Librarieis like Moment.js. Using moment.js would be a better/easier way to handle date/time instead coding from scratch

just run this in the terminal:

```
npm install moment --save
```

And in your React Native js page:

import Moment from 'moment';

```
render(){
    Moment.locale('en');
    var dt = '2016-05-02T00:00:00';
    return(<View> {Moment(dt).format('d MMM')} </View>) //basically you can do all sorts of the formatting and others
}
```

You may check the moment.js offical docs at here https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Im happy thats its fixed now :)